# Core data tutorial

Tags: core-data, ios7

I had been developing an app using sqlite recently. But now in my existing app I want to use core data in it. Can you suggest me a tutorial which not just teaches about basic, but how to create a relationship and adding a version to that core data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for beginners you will find Ray Wenderlich has some great tutorials for most iOS stuff. Heres one on [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

Comment: Thank you for the tutorials it helped me :)